# Dynamic Role Attributes in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like the Chef cookbook `network_interfaces` to have dynamic values for ip addresses, netmasks and alike for each of my nodes. What works for me is the following:

db_role.rb (block1):

```
override_attributes(
  "network_interfaces" => {
      :device => 'eth0',
      :address => '123.123.123.123',
  }
)
```

But that is not very dynamic. My idea was to submit the ip address(, netmask, etc.) to each node on `knife bootstrap`.

The node would then look like so (block2):

```
{
    "normal": {
      "network_interfaces" => {
          "device" : "eth0",
          "address" : "123.123.123.123"
      }
    },
    "name": "foobar",
    "run_list": [
       "recipe[zsh]",
       "role[networking_interfaces]"
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately the `network_interfaces` cookbook does not pick up those values by default. My idea was to reference the node specific attributes shown in block2 in the roles definition like so:

```
override_attributes(
  "network_interfaces" => {
      :device => node['network_interfaces']['device'],
      :address => node['network_interfaces']['address'],
  }
)
```

This does not work because it is not json obviously and Chef can not handle dynamically allocated values in roles files.

How can I achieve to run the `network_interfaces` recipe and pass my node specific values to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add *normal* attributes via `knife bootstrap -j …`, and leave *override* attributes in the role, the *override* will take over (see http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_node_object_attributes_precedence.html for a complete list of attribute precedence). If you have deleted `override_attributes` from `db_role.rb` before running `knife bootstrap`, or changed it to `default_attributes`, then setting IP in node attributes should have worked.

The last snippet won't work: roles are static JSON documents on the Chef server, and Ruby is only interpreted once by `knife` when uploading role to the server (http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles_formats.html). You can't refer to node's attributes from role's Ruby code, as it's compiled to JSON before it even touches any node. If you want to try a similar approach, you need to use a custom cookbook (say, `my_network_interfaces`) with a recipe that would look somewhat like this:

```
node.set['network_interface']['device'] = …
node.set['network_interface']['address'] = …
include_recipe 'network_interfaces'
```

This way, you'd use `network_interfaces` as a "library" cookbook, called by your "application" cookbook `my_network_interfaces` which implements whatever logic you need. From your question, I can't suggest how would you compute device and address, as your example just tries to copy same attributes, which is a no-op. As far as I understand what you want to achieve, you want to have `default_attributes` in the role, and pass specific JSON with *normal* attributes to `knife bootstrap` to override the defaults.

Answer (score 6):

Maciej, I followed your suggestions. 
I upload the custom parameters like IP, broadcast, etc with the -j option upon bootstrap.

```
knife bootstrap IP_OF_THE_NODE -r 'role[main_application]' -j '{ "network_interfaces" : {"device" : "eth1.0000", "type" : "static", "address" : "192.168.1.1", "netmask" : "255.255.255.0", "broadcast" : "192.168.0.255","gateway": "192.168.0.1"}}'
```

Plus I wrote a custom recipe to achieve the dynamic matching. Here's the code:

```
#setup a custom network config per vm
network_interfaces node["network_interfaces"]["device"] do
  Chef::Log.info("Compiling network_interfaces")
  target node["network_interfaces"]["address"]
  mask node["network_interfaces"]["netmask"]
  broadcast node["network_interfaces"]["broadcast"]
  gateway node["network_interfaces"]["gateway"]
  custom node["network_interfaces"]["custom"]
  action :save
end
```

Comment: -j only accepts url and file path in the latest version atleast
which version of chef you have used?

Comment: What @j7nn7k provided is correct. Perhaps you got confused about `chef-client` options @AkD, see https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3965#comment-33163