# Best Practice for setting unique Chef Node Attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I am attempting to use Chef to manage new virtual machines.  I'm using a dedicated Chef server and doing all this work from a separate workstation vm.

The way I am currently doing it is cloning a base vm image then using knife bootstrap to install Chef and bring the vm to a consistent state.

I can specify an environment or run list for the vm; I can override certain settings in my environment, e.g. I have the [chef-client](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/chef-client) interval in the "overrides" block of the test environment set to run the client every 60 while I'm testing so I don't have to manually run chef-client every time.

For instance, my workflow is this:

- clone vm template and start vm
- set the hostname manually (update /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts) and reboot
- Bootstrap the node with the initial recipes

  > knife bootstrap chef-test1 -r 'recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client]'
- edit the node to reflect the new environment

The problem I am having is setting per-node attributes.   I would like to use the [hostname](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/hostname) cookbook to set the node's hostname, if I set this in a role then each server would have to have a new role created.  But when I attempt to bootstrap and include this role I get an error:

```
chef-test1   * log[Please set the set_fqdn attribute to desired hostname] action write[2013-12-09T16:26:56-07:00] WARN: Please set the set_fqdn attribute to desired hostname
```

When I bootstrap without that recipe and attempt to edit the node and set the "set_fqdn" attribute, I am unable to save the attribute, e.g. this json:

```
{
  "name": "chef-test1",
  "set_fqdn": "chef-test1.local.fqdn",
  "chef_environment": "test-dev1",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [

    ]
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[ntp]",
    "recipe[chef-client]",
    "recipe[hostname]"
  ]
}
```

when I exit out of my editor, knife tells me:

```
Node not updated, skipping node save
```

I attempted to edit this attribute in the chef gui and the attribute won't save.

I found [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381843/how-to-set-node-attributes-on-a-chef-client) who is creating the json in /etc/chef/chef.json, doing basically what I would expect, but I'm not sure how /etc/chef/chef.json comes into play (update it for each new node?  I'm not using chef-solo so maybe that's where my confusion is).

According to [this email thread](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2011-10/msg00360.html) it's not possible to override default attributes with knife node edit, but "set_fqdn" isn't a default.  I would like to avoid creating a role for each node, and I think I can use the hostname cookbook to alleviate the need to manually set the hostname, something like:

> knife bootstrap saucy64 -r 'recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client],recipe[hostname]' --json '"{ set_fqdn": "chef-test1.local.tld", "chef_client": { "interval": "600" }'
>
> knife bootstrap fedora19 -r 'recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client],recipe[hostname]' --json '"{ set_fqdn": "chef-test2.local.tld", "chef_client": { "interval": "60" }'

I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: i am struggling on the same to set the hostname using chef of ec2 instances. please help

Answer (score 6):

I see some problems:

- during `knife node edit`, you can't set the attribute as a top-level attribute next to fqdn etc. You have to place it below `normal`. This is the hierarchy between `default` and `override`. See [Attribute Precedence](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_overview_attributes.html#attribute-precedence)
- using `knife node edit` smells. I'd rather not do this (might be okay for the host name, but for everything else it's impossible to track such changes in version control). Try to get the `hostname` cookbook running instead.
- writing attributes out to a `chef.json` file should be IMHO also avoided. Your logic should be inside your cookbooks
- you should have a `base` role / cookbook or similar that includes the trivial things that every node has (like `ntp`, `chef-client` and also the hostname).
- you can set the environment also directly during [bootstrapping](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_bootstrap.html): `-E myenv` (but yes, I'm wondering why this isn't documented)
- you can set the node name during bootstrapping, too: `-N NAME` or `--node-name NAME`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  (no new lines in comments so I apologize for the jumble of text in response to your nice list).  - So it looks like  the easiest would be to create a role for each new vm where I can set "set_fqdn" in the override block; the other thought in the back of my mind is a way to autogenerate the name but I think that's down the road.  - Ok. I was really just trying to get the cookbook to work somehow, I think I understand how this could get unruly long term.  - how would I accomplish this?  Maybe a "base" cookbook that grabs the hostname from a databag?

Comment: - ok, good idea.  Thanks.  - it actually is documented under `knife help bootstrap` or `knife boostrap --help` thanks for pointing that out though, that alleviates the need to edit it after bootstraping.  - setting the node name only sets it for chef though, it doesn't change the hostname name of the node.

Comment: Here's another [hostname cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/lxmx_hostname) that indicates: `Usage
To set and persist a hostname, set node['net']['hostname'].
To set and persist an FQDN, set node['net']['FQDN'] and node['net']['IP'].
Then include recipe[lxmx_hostname] in your run_list.`, but where would I set those attributes?

Comment: well, there is a "normal" block that I can edit, but as we've already discussed that is less than optimal.

Comment: As suggested by user1106405 I would let a cookbook write out the `/etc/hosts` and thus set the host name based on the node name that you set during bootstrapping. Or you just set up your servers correctly before you start with Chef. What you suggest really sounds like things I wouldn't want to do.

Comment: i am struggling on the same to set the hostname using chef of ec2 instances. please help..

Answer (score 2):

how about a recipe that sets the hostname based on the defined node.name when you bootstrap the node, I [wrote one](https://github.com/three18ti/chef-cookbook-hostname) which is a fork of the original chef-hostname cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
knife bootstrap 192.168.15.43 -r 'recipe[hostname],recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client]' -j '{"set_fqdn": "chef-test2"}'
```

(also found reading `knife help bootstrap` help)

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14317381/1106405) uses similar syntax.

Edit:  Well, almost, this creates two node entries.  need to specify the node name with the -N parameter:

```
knife bootstrap 192.168.15.43 -r 'recipe[hostname],recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client]' -j '{"set_fqdn": "chef-test2"}' -N chef-test2

knife bootstrap 192.168.15.43 --run-list 'recipe[hostname],recipe[ntp],recipe[chef-client]' --json-attributes '{"set_fqdn": "chef-test2"}' --node-name chef-test2
```

Comment: also, specify the environment with the -E flag instead of using _default